# Don't understand the diffrence between 2 AAD features

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am reading this doc:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn532272.aspx

Among the differences between the 3 AAD version I see this:

**Common features**

Self-service password change for cloud users

**Premium and Basic features**

Self-service password reset for cloud users

What is the difference?

Answer (score 0):

One is `password change` which would allow a user to change her/his own password and this would require a user to know the password while the other is `password reset` which would allow an administrator to regenerate the password for a user without actually knowing the user's password. Please see this link which explains it clearly: http://webactivedirectory.com/active-directory/understand-the-difference-between-a-password-reset-and-password-change-in-active-directory/.